# Using identify's pearl for homunculus summoning?

Tags: dnd-5e, spell-components, artificer

My artificer acquired a pearl to cast identify. Would he be able to also use it to create a homunculus servant, as pearls could be classified as gems in the real world?

Comment: Because there are now some number of different ways to get homunculi, which one are specifically asking about?

Comment: Are you asking whether or not the pearl is consumed in the casting of the homunculus servant creation?  We know that it isn't consumed during the casting of identify.

Answer (score 13):

#### Yes, a pearl counts as a gem and is usable for both *Identify* and the Artificer's *Homunculus Servant* ability.

Page 134 of the DMG provides tables of gemstones that can be found/given as treasure. A pearl is specifically listed as a gemstone worth 100GP.

Comment: If used for the homunculus servant, is it usable anymore for _identify_?  The gem "serves as the creature's heart, around which the creature's body instantly forms."

Comment: @LouisWasserman which raises the actual question, which is "is the pearl consumed in the casting of the spell" which our querent hasn't quite fit into the question.

Comment: @LouisWasserman As long as that pearl is serving the purpose of being the homunculus servant's heart, you can't exactly use it as a material component. "A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell's material components", hence you can't access the parl while it is inside of the homunculus. The pearl is not consumed as part of casting _identify_, since the spell does not state it is consumed, nor it is consumed by the infusion, since "If you or the homunculus dies, it (the homunculus) vanishes, leaving its heart (the pearl) in its space".

Comment: @KogarashiKaito The spell does not state the heart is inaccessible while within the homunculus.  An example homunculus is an animated miniature cauldron, which could just have its pearl heart rolling around the base: reach in, cast identify, leave it in the pot when you're done..

Comment: @JonAristotle It doesn't need to tell you that: it already says that its body forms around it and that it functions as its heart. If the pearl/gemstone were to be accessible still when the homunculus servant is in function, then there would be no need to use it or specify how the homunculus's body forms around it in the first place. You are free to rule it as you want in your game, but to me it's pretty clear that the pearl is now inside the homunculus and cannot be retrieved until it comes out (when the homunculus is no longer alive or not infused, that is).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a pearl is on the "gemstones" treasure chart, so it appears to be considered a gemstone for the purposes of the game.

However, note that if you use a pearl to act as the heart of a homunculus, it's no longer available to be used as the material component for *identify*, since it's integrated into the body of the homunculus.